# Dynamic styling of marker based on todays date

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to work out whether it is possible to change the icon based on whether the date associated with the marker matches todays

For example, I have a series of events for which I wish to show the location of on a google map (the data is loaded as a fusion-table). I wish to show all of these events but I wish to have a different icon for those events which match the date on which the map is loaded.

Does anyone know of any examples which demonstrate this? I've had a good search but can't find anything.

Update:
I've come back to this after working on other stuff but still can't get this to work well. The code posted above works well to create the current date string, but I am then not getting any query that tries to use this string/var to work. I think I must be missing something very obvious, as when I input a date manually into the query everything works as it should.

I've pasted my code snippet below...would be grateful if someone could point out what might be wrong.

```
var d = new Date();
var mon = d.getMonth() + 1; 
var day = d.getDate(); 
var year = d.getFullYear();
var date_string = '';
 if(mon < 10){
     date_string += "0" + mon; }else{
     date_string += mon; } 
     date_string += '/'; if(day < 10){
     date_string += "0" + day; }else{
     date_string += day; }
  date_string += '/'; year -= 2000;
 date_string += year;
  alert(date_string); 

layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'Latitude',
            from: '3xxxxxx'
        },
        styles: [{ markerOptions: { iconName: "measle_white" } },
         { where: "'Date' = 'date_string'", 
        markerOptions: { iconName: "wht_pushpin"} }, 
        {where: "'Date' <= '05/07/12'", 
        markerOptions: { iconName: "measle_white" } }]


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the question changed, see comment. But note that if you just want the current date, >= will work for the Fusion Table query,  even if = does not.

```
var d = new Date();
var mon = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();

var date_string = '';
if(mon < 10){
    date_string += "0" + mon;
}else{
    date_string += mon;
}
date_string += '/';
if(day < 10){
    date_string += "0" + day;
}else{
    date_string += day;
}

date_string += '/';
year -= 2000;
date_string += year;

alert(date_string);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible but you have not indicated what if anything you have tried so far. I'm not aware of any examples but there are a number demonstrating using a time slider with Fusion Tables which are probably worth searching on.

I recently answered a question about Fusion Tables [datetime filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635569/issue-to-query-data-filtered-by-date-from-fusion-table/9639824#9639824).  The take away is to ensure your Fusion Table column is typed as datetime and also to ensure your dates use the accepted datetime formats.

Here's a code snippet which might accomplish what you want.

```
var where_date = "where Date = '03/13/12'";
var ftOpts = {
  query: {
     select: location_col,
     from: current_table_id
  },
  styles: [ {
      where: where_date,
      markerOptions:{
          iconName: "small_green"
       },
    },
    {
      markerOptions:{
          iconName: "small_red"
       },
    }
 ]
};

curr_layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(ftOpts);

curr_layer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. I think my main problem would be generating the current date (ie - how could I define what todays date would be). I've seen code similar to yours so I'm confident I could replicate that (although I would need to get the 'equals' working) my stumbling block would be specifying the current date...

Comment: You should have asked on the Javascript list.  See the [Date reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) But it's easy to do and an add another answer.

Comment: I've come back to this after working on other stuff but still can't get this to work well. The code posted above works well to create the current date string, but I am then not getting any query that tries to use this string/var to work. I think I must be missing something very obvious, as when I input a date manually into the query everything works as it should.